# Laravel vue-router getting single data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to return my data such as `posts` by their `slug` but so far I couldn't make it by `Vue-router`

## Code

`controller`

```
public function single($slug)
    {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return response()->json([
            "post" => $post
        ], 200);
    }
```

`blog.vue`

```
    <li v-for="post in posts" :key="post.slug">
      <router-link to="/blog/${post.slug}">{{ post.title }}</router-link>
    </li>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'list',
        mounted() {
            if (this.posts.length) {
                return;
            }

            this.$store.dispatch('getPosts');
        },
        computed: {
            posts() {
                return this.$store.getters.posts;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`vuex store.js`

```
state: {
        posts: []
    },
getters: {
        posts(state) {
            return state.posts;
        }
    },
mutations: {
        updatePosts(state, payload) {
            state.posts = payload;
        }
    },
actions: {
        getPosts(context) {
            axios.get('/api/posts')
            .then((response) => {
                context.commit('updatePosts', response.data.posts);
            })
        }
    }
```

## Problem

The problem is that i get this kind of url in my loop

```
site.pp/blog/${post.slug}
```

I should get something like:

```
site.pp/blog/hello-world
```

## Question

1. Where did I make mistake? and how to fix it?

Comment: should be `:to="\`/blog/${post.slug}\`"` . If it's not using v-bind, it's considered plain text.

Comment: @JacobGoh thank you it's working however i can't get single post data (probably i need make new question :-p)